# Is it possible to get SWT to use OS X native tabs?

Tags: java, macos, swt

I'm working on an SWT app, and although I greatly appreciate the way SWT looks compared to other Java toolkits, I'm disappointed with how "tabs" are implemented. What I'm looking for is OS X's native way of showing these tabs, and I'm hoping there's a way to do that in SWT. Here's what my app's tabs look like now:

[image]

And here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

I'd also prefer a way that looks native on other platforms as well (the very reason I'm using SWT). But if there is an OS X-specific method, that could work, as I already have the code for each platform separate.

Comment: Is this an RCP app or straight SWT?  If the latter, have you tried `TabFolder` instead of `CTabFolder`?

Comment: Ha yeah that's what I wanted. Took me a while to get all the code to work. Why don't you put it into an answer?

Comment: Yep, you bet, created an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above screenshot is a picture of the SWT `CTabFolder`, which avoids the native widgets and draws its own tabs.  Since SWT tends to provide a least-common-denominator approach to wrapping the native widgets, `CTabFolder` can provide functionality that the native tabs do not necessarily provide.

If you prefer the native tabs, like you see in the second screenshot, you can use a [`TabFolder`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TabFolder.html) to achieve that.